# Proving an entire function is constant if it satisfies some conditions.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ s.t there exists
> $a>0$ and $f(z)=f(z+a)=f(z+ia)$ for every $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Prove that
> $f$ is constant.

Let $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y), z=x+yi$. From hypothesis we have $$u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=u(x+a,y)+iv(x+a,y)=u(x,y+a)+iv(x,y+a)\quad\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Also, since $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, the Cauchy-Riemann equation is satisfied
$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$ $$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\dfrac{-\partial v}{\partial x}.$$
I don't know how to continue. Could someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question up for 18 minutes, 11 views, and 4 upvotes, for what is basically a "I have no idea how to do my homework" question? Sometimes this place mystifies me.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thank you!